# Как взять координаты мыши при клике относительно окна tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Реализовал по bind но координаты берёт относительно виджету которая находится под курсором.

```
import tkinter as tk
def getorigin(eventorigin):
      global x,y
      x = eventorigin.x
      y = eventorigin.y
      print(x,y)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Button 1>",getorigin)

root.mainloop()
```

Вот функция которую я нашёл. Но мне нужно взять координаты относительно окна Tkinter.

Comment: какие знаете решения

Comment: Почитайте документацию по tkinter, или  забейте в гугол по теме координаты курсора на окне или виджете tkinter.

Comment: весь гугл пролазил ни единого решения.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428593/getting-the-absolute-position-of-cursor-in-tkinter

Comment: Этот код даёт абсолютные координаты (относително монитора).Мне нужны координаты относительно окна Tkinter

Comment: Я не первый раз слышу про  координаты, но что вам нужно не могу понять, объясните нормально.

Comment: Как понять относительно окна?

Comment: Не морочьте голову, вы ссылке которую привёл  Интик как раз и показывается как узнать координаты относительно окна.

Answer (score 2):

Наслаждайтесь

```
from tkinter import *
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('500x500')


    def run(self):
        self.interface()
        self.root.mainloop()


    def interface(self):
        self.root.bind('<Motion>', self.move)


    def move(self, event):
        x = event.x
        y = event.y

        print(x, y)

A = Main()
A.run()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: хорошая аватарка!